# vue2-datepicker mobile UX and performance

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

datepicker
https://mengxiong10.github.io/vue2-datepicker/index.html

I have been checking all props available and I am not able to get a solution, the thing is that when I load the range-datepicker in mobile I need to load at least 12 months in mobile in order to change the months when I scroll the calendar, instead click in the controls, I am showing a fullscreen calendar for better UX.

I can trigger the controls when scrolling and change months but performance is not so good.

Anybody knows if this library can do that?